# Insert data into the file as an array in bash

Tags: node.js, bash, unix

With the below command, i'm writing data into `file.txt`.

```
node scripts/js/script.js /home/desktop/my-file.mp3 > file.txt
```

The content of `file.txt`:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0.00003051850947599719
0
-0.00003051850947599719
0
0.00006103701895199438
0
```

What should be way such that it writes the data in the form of an array?
Like this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00003051850947599719, 0, -0.00003051850947599719, 0, 0.00006103701895199438, 0]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will asume that you cannot change `scripts/js/script.js` and will therefore show you a script that makes an intermediate step between your node script and the output file:

One way is to use the following GNU sed script:

```
node ... | sed 's/"/\\"/;s/$/,/;1s/^/[/;$s/,$/]/' > file.txt
```

If you don't want to preserve the newlines you can pipe to tr:

```
node ... | sed 's/"/\\"/;s/$/,/;1s/^/[/;$s/,$/]/' | tr -d '\n' > file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. It works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is, use `JSON.stringify()`:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00003051850947599719, 0, -0.00003051850947599719, 0, 0.00006103701895199438, 0];

fs.writeFile('file.txt', JSON.stringify(arr), function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Sorry it is new for me. This is JS right ?

Comment: Sure, call it script.js and run by `node script.js`

Comment: Actually, i need to read the data from a file and then write that in a file in form of an array. Here you're assuming an already formed array.

Comment: Can you show us your current code so we can alter that to display what you want?

Comment: Actually i wont be able to share the code on a public platform. But as of now @andlrc's answer worked!!

Answer (score 0):

This solves your problem:

```
content=( `cat "file.txt" `)

for i in "${content[@]}"
do
    echo $i
done
```